# Why I can still do gradle build inside android studio without jdk installed?

Tags: android, gradle

First time installed Android Studio on a Mac, checked no JDK,

```
MacBook-Pro:~/sh$ java --version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.

MacBook-Pro:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents$ ls
Info.plist  Resources   bin     jre     license
MacOS       _CodeSignature  gradle      lib     plugins
```

And then I opened Android Studio and wrote the universal simple program "hello" and built it, I expected error, but none ... (see the build console highlight part)

[image]

Again, I expected error like "jdk not installed" "no found jdk" "java not found" etc ...

I tried use command line to do build, then again

```
MacBook-Pro:~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3/bin$ ./gradle -v
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

I felt mutual exclusive here, unless Android Studio built project not using Gradle.

So how on earth to understand Gradle role in Android Studio correctly?

---

Put the location in case someone need it,

```
MacBook-Pro:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin$ ls
appletviewer    javah       jjs     keytool     schemagen
extcheck    javap       jmap        native2ascii    serialver
idlj        jcmd        jps     orbd        servertool
jar     jconsole    jrunscript  pack200     tnameserv
jarsigner   jdb     jsadebugd   policytool  unpack200
java        jdeps       jstack      rmic        wsgen
javac       jhat        jstat       rmid        wsimport
javadoc     jinfo       jstatd      rmiregistry xjc
```

Comment: It has its own JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Android Studio 2.2 the OpenJDK is embedded. If you want to use a different version you can do so. [See here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk)

By using the gradle wrapper it will use your environment path to the JDK which you did not set up. That's why it's working in Android Studio but not from the OS command line.

Comment: Thanks, when doing "Run", we need SDK, any deep understanding on JDK vs SDK?